# GAE/J request log format breakdown

Tags: google-app-engine, console, cloud, logging

Here is a sample of GAE Console log record:

[image: GAE log console snapshot] https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2iJX.png for readable high res version.

I would like to provide a breakdown of the fileds, displayed both in the collpased (summary) view and the expended (detail) view. I will fill the fields I know their meaning and would appreciate assistannce with dichipering the rest. This post will be updated once new information is available.

Thank you,
Maxim.

---

Open issues:

- How to read timestamp? [...-prod/0-0-39.**346862139187007139**]
- Why in summary it says request took 343ms but in details is says 344ms ?
- If request spend 123ms on cpu and 30ms on API calls where did the rest of the time go? Why the total request time is 343/344ms ?

Comment: Good summary, but this isn't a question: either post it somewhere else, or modify it so the question asks how the logs are structured, and post the rest as an answer.

Comment: @Nick, thank you for the comment. Don't you think this could serve as a viable resource for the GAE community? I would appreciate if you could help with the missing fields section (please see "open issues" at the bottom of the post).

Comment: I agree it could - but it needs to be posted properly, with an actual question ('what do all these fields mean?') as the question, and the answers as an answer. Also, FWIW, I've been planning a blog post explaining the logs in detail for a while. :)

Comment: I'd support someone with sufficient rep removing the answer from the question. I'd even upvote the question once it's cleaned up ;)

Comment: I have made the refactoring as you suggested.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Summary

- **12-14** : Date of the request. **12** is the month (December), **14** is the day of the month (Tuesday).
- **05:21AM** : Time of the request, [PST](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1102#c4) offset. **05** is the hour. **21** is the minute.
- **57.593** : Time of request, [PST](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1102#c4) offset. **57** is the second. **593** is the millisecond.
- **/match/...** : HTTP request path
- **200** : HTTP return code. (200 = OK)
- **343ms** : The total time (in milliseconds) it took to calculate and return the response to the user
- **123cpu_ms** : The time (in milliseconds) the request spend on CPU calculation
- **30api_cpu_ms** : The time (in milliseconds) the request spend on API calls (Datastore get and co...)
- **1kb** : The size (in kilobytes) of the response that was sent to the user
- **Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.44 Safari/534.7,gzip(gfe)** : [User Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) note that gzip(gfe) is added by AppEngine front end.

## Details

- **IP** `yellow masked out` : The IP address of the client initiating the request
- **HTTP Referrer** : Note that it's empty on this request because it's a direct hit
- **[14/Dec/2010:05:21:57 -0800]** : Date, including timestamp offset specification.
- **"GET /match/... HTTP/1.1"** : The HTTP GET URI.
- **200** : HTTP return code. (200 = OK)
- **1036** : The size (in bytes) of the response that was sent to the user
- **Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.44 Safari/534.7,gzip(gfe)** : [User Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) note that gzip(gfe) is added by AppEngine front end.
- **ms=344** : The total time (in milliseconds) it took to calculate and return the response to the user
- **cpu_ms=123** : The time (in milliseconds) the request spend on CPU calculation
- **api_cpu_ms=30** : The time (in milliseconds) the request spend on API calls (Datastore get and co...)
- **cpm_usd=0.003648** : The amount (in us $) that 1000 requests such as this one would cost. [ref](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#Responses)

### log record

- **12-14** : Date of this specific application emitted log entry. **12** is the month (December), **14** is the day of the month (Tuesday).
- **05:21AM** : Time of this specific application emitted log entry, [PST](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1102#c4) offset.
- **57.833** : Time of request, [PST](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1102#c4) offset. **57** is the second. **833** is the millisecond.
- **[...-prod/0-0-39.346862139187007139]** : The identifier of current version of the application that emitted this log message. Note: **...-prod** is the application name. **0-0-39** is the deployed version name (app.yaml). **.346862139187007139** is the time? (in what format?) when this version was deployed to appengine cloud.
- **stdout** : The channel to which the application emitted this log message. Can be either stdout or stderr.
- **INFO ....Matcher - ... Id 208 matched.** : Application level output. Can be done via either System.out.print or (as in this case) using a logging framework, [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)

Comment: Is cpm_usd daily or monthly? Say cpm_usd=0.001, and 1,000,000 such operations are done daily, then monthly cost would be 1$ or 30$?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't **57.593** seconds.milliseconds?
And **cpm_usd** represents an estimate of what 1,000 requests similar to this request would cost in US dollars.

Comment: Seems to be correct, Thanks. Could you provide a reference for the cpm_usd field ?

Comment: I found that from the [response documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#Responses).