# Google App Engine - does instance hours include upload / download time by HTTP client to server?

Tags: google-app-engine, instance

I have an application hosted on the Google App Engine platform. The application is mostly I/O intensive and involves a high number of upload and download operations to the app engine server by an HTTP client.

My question is: what does the instance hour comprise of in this case ? Does it include the total time taken by the HTTP client to upload the request data ? Or does the instance hour calculation begin when the entire request data is uploaded and processing of the request starts ?

Example results from the application:

- An HTTP client sent an upload request to the app engine server, request data size 1.1 MB

  Time taken for request to complete on the client side - 78311 ms

  Corresponding server log entry:

- - [Time] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 127 - "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)" "" ms=3952 cpu_ms=1529 api_cpu_ms=283 cpm_usd=0.154248 instance=

- An HTTP client sent a download request to the app engine server.

  Time taken for request to complete on the client side - 8632 ms

  Corresponding server log entry:

- - [Time] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 297910 - "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)" "" ms=909 cpu_ms=612 api_cpu_ms=43 cpm_usd=0.050377 instance=

Which of these figures contributes towards the instance hour utilization - is it a) ms, b) cpu_ms or c) the time taken for request to complete on the client side ?

Please note that the HTTP client uses a FileEntity while uploading data, therefore I assume that data is sent over by the client to the server in a single part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incoming requests are buffered by the App Engine infrastructure, and the request is only passed to an instance of your app once the entire request has been received. Likewise, outgoing requests are buffered, and your app does not have to wait for the user to finish downloading the response. As a result, upload and download time are not charged against your app.

Answer (score 2):

To understand numbers in log look at [log breakdown](http://blog.notdot.net/2011/06/Demystifying-the-App-Engine-request-logs), a bit more readable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440159/gae-j-request-log-format-breakdown).

None of the options you presented (a. b. c.) are directly billed. It used to be that GAE counted CPU time as a unit of cost, but that changed Nov 2011. Now you pay for instance uptime, even if instance is not handling any requests. Instances stop being billed [after 15 min of inactivity](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/billing#time_granularity_instance_pricing).

(This does not mean that GAE actually shuts instances down after they stop billing for them - see "Instances" graph in your dashboard.)

How many instances are up depends on your app's [performance settings](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings).

Since your app is IO intensive it will help to enable concurrent requests ([Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Using_Concurrent_Requests), [Python 2.7](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Using_Concurrent_Requests)). This way instance can run multiple parallel requests which are mainly waiting for IO - in our app I'm seeing about 15-20 requests being served in parallel on one instance.

**Update:**

This is what [first link](http://blog.notdot.net/2011/06/Demystifying-the-App-Engine-request-logs) says about `ms=xyz` log entry:

```
This is the actual time (hence 'wallclock' time) taken to return a response to 
the user, not including the time it took for the user to send their request or 
the time it takes to send the response back - that is, just the time spent 
processing by your app.
```

Note that Nick Johnson is an engineer on GAE team, so this can be taken as authoritative answer.

Comment: If content served is going through caching proxies than it's absolutely possible that client request duration and server request duration are different. Actually, there is a caching proxy in front of App Engine, that will cache content if you set cache header (`Cache-Control`): http://www.kyle-jensen.com/proxy-caching-on-google-appengine

Comment: To see cached requests, see graph "Requests by Type" in your GAE dashboard

Comment: my question is related to the inclusion of time taken by a client to upload / download data to the app engine server. Is this time included in the instance hour calculation ? When is an instance attached to a request - Is it after the entire request data gets uploaded to the server or is it spawned as soon as the request header is received on the server side ?

Comment: the requests are of a dynamic nature so I am not sure whether a caching proxy would help me to decrease instance hour usage.

Comment: So, this is request processing time only. But this will not help you decrease the cost. What will is parallel requests.